# SharePoint doesn't create mysite

Tags: my-site, timer-jobs, mysite

I configured Mysite on Sharepoint 2013 by creating a new webapp and a root site collection but no site collection is created when user click on "About Me". It redirects to my.xxxx/person.aspx

If i check in CA no jobs are scheduled. If i read documentation when a user doesn't have a mysite yet. it created with a job : Instantiation Interactive Request Queue

Self service creation is enabled on my webapplication mysite and managed path is added for "personal"
I added mysite settings in user profile service.

I supposed issue is no one jobs are running but services sharepoint administration or timer are running

Comment: Did you create a MySite Host Site-Collection as root in your MySite-WebApplication?

Answer (score 0):

To get MySite to work all the way, you need to

- Create a My Site host site collection
- Add a wildcard inclusion managed path to the Web application
- Connect the Web application to service applications
- Enable self-service site creation for the Web application
- Configure My Site settings for the User Profile service application
- Enable the User Profile Service Application - Activity Feed Job

Check that everything is configured because it's easy to miss a step or two.

See [Configure My Sites in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)